# Apply reduce method for all properties of an object

Tags: laravel, collections, reduce

I have an object in Laravel that represent a monthly report.

```
  0 => array:20 [▼
    "id" => 43
    "operation_id" => 1
    "meter_id" => 3
    "period" => "monthly"      
    "total_conso" => "103.42"
    "total_autoconso" => "59.47"
    "total_grid" => "43.95"
    "bill" => "31.95"
    "grid_fee" => "26.97"
    "solar_turpe_tax_fee" => "4.99"
    "savings" => "4.41"
    "total_prod" => null
    "total_surplus" => null
    "autoconso_rate" => "57.5"
    "autoprod_rate" => null
    "surplus_rate" => null
    "date" => "2019-08-24T00:00:00.000000Z"
    "created_at" => "2019-08-24T00:00:00.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2020-10-01T15:03:38.000000Z"
```

I have a array with 12 objects of these, one per month.

I am calculating the yearly report values, and I have to sum all 12 month for each field.

I can do it with reduce field by field with:

```
$totalConso = $reports->reduce(function ($sum, $report) {
            return $sum + $report->total_conso;
        }, 0);
```

What I am looking for is a way to do it for all fields. Is it possible ? It would allow me not to duplicate 10 times the same `reduce` function

Thanks !

Comment: you can manually do that by a simple foreach loop. ;)

Comment: I could do it, but I hate loops XD. I will do it if there is no better options

Comment: but sometimes those are actually performance booster(here 12 to 1) and with simplicity. Still you can use `array_map` or `array_walk` but they will do the same looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```php
[$totalConso, $totalAutoConso] = collect(['total_conso', 'total_autoconso'])->map(fn ($property) => $reports->sum($property));
```

---

If you would prefer an array with each total:

```php
$totals = collect(['total_conso', 'total_autoconso'])->mapWithKeys(fn ($property) => [$property => $reports->sum($property)]);
```

This would give you a collection with all the totals.

If you don't like hardcoding the list of `total_*` attributes, you can get them dynamically from the list of `fillable` attributes of your model (this assumes you use the `fillable` property):

```php
$totals = collect(Report::make()->fillable)
    ->filter(fn ($property) => strpos($property, 'total_') === 0)
    ->mapWithKeys(fn ($property) => [$property => $reports->sum($property)]);
```

Demo: https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/ec3c662f-0ab9-4de8-8422-7bed2f054677

Answer (score 2):

Use the [collect](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-collect) helper and `sum` method:

```
$total = collect($reports)->sum('total_conso');
```

Comment: oohhh, this is better than using reduce function. But question remains. How should I apply sum() to all fields in my object

Comment: No need `collect`, it's already a collection of reports.